# How to compare two strings and replace non-matching letters with -?

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to write a program to compare two strings, pick out the mismatching bits, and replace them with "-"

ex.) `go("boo" , "foo") returns -oo`

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
String go( String a, String b ) {
  String c = "";
  String q = "-";
  int al = a.length();
  for(int i = 0; i < al; i++){
     char ch = a.charAt(i);
     if(b.indexOf(a)!= -1) {
       c = c + String.valueOf(ch);
     } else {
       c = c + q;
     }
   }
 return c;
 }
```

Comment: Why the JavaScript tag? Are you trying to match strictly by position of letters, or would `go("boo", "whoo")` return `"--oo"`?

Comment: I'm doing this based on the assumption that the two strings are the same length, so  go("feed", "deed") would return "-eed".

Comment: Why do you use `ch = a.charAt(i)`. And then `c = c + String.valueOf(ch)` instead of just doing `c = c + a.charAt(i)`?

Comment: Also, why do you do `String q = "-"` and then `c = c + q` instead of just doing `c = c + "-"`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) in order to quickly and easily mutate a string, and then return the `toString()` value. You can use [`setCharAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt-int-char-) in order to change the characters at certain indexes.

This code assumes that `str1.length() == str2.length()` as a pre-condition.

```
public String escapeDifferentCharacters(String str1, String str2) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str1);
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        if (str1.charAt(i) != str2.charAt(i)) {
            result.setCharAt(i, '-');
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with regex:

```
String str1 = "boo";
String str2 = "foo";

System.out.println(str1.replaceAll("[^"+str2+"]","-"));

     (or)

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^"+str1+"]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str2);
System.out.println(m.replaceAll("-"));
```

output:

-oo